# php oci_bind_by_name not working in loop

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to bind by name in a `foreach` loop which does not seem to be working.

**Old way working:**

```
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':exemptionid', $exemption_id, 10, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':seq', $seq, 10, SQLT_INT);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':action', $action, 20, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':s_zone',$sourceZones,48,SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':s_seczone',$szone1,32,SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':d_zone',$destinationZones,48,SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':d_seczone',$dzone1,32,SQLT_CHR);
if($protocol_id != null) {
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':protocolid', $protocol_id, 10, SQLT_INT);
}
if($ports != null) {
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':ports', $ports, 32, SQLT_CHR);
}
if($note != null) {
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':note', $note, 128, SQLT_CHR);
}
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':method', $method, 1, SQLT_CHR);
$authuser = authUser();
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':authuser', $authuser, 64, SQLT_CHR);
```

But when I put this all into an array and put in function and try process it in a loop it fails binding integers.

**Not WORKING**

```
function bind($resource, $binds){
    foreach ($binds as $placeholder => $varibale){
        oci_bind_by_name($resource,$placeholder, $varibale[0],$varibale[1],$varibale[2]);
    }
}

$binds = [
    ':exemptionid' => [
        $exemption_id,
        10,
        SQLT_INT
    ],
    ':source' => [
        ($source != "") ? $source : $sourceZones,
        strlen ($source),
        SQLT_CHR
    ],
    ':destination' => [
        ($destination != "" ) ? $destination : $destinationZones,
        strlen ($destination),
        SQLT_CHR
    ]
];

if ($protocol_id != null) {
    $binds [':protocolid'] = [
        $protocol_id,
        10,
        SQLT_INT
    ];
}
if ($ports != null) {
    $binds [':ports'] = [
        $ports,
        32,
       SQLT_CHR
    ];
}

bind($resource, $binds); // not working
```

The error I get is `oci_execute(): ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column` but none of my columns have decimals and I am not passing any decimals.

**UPDATE**

Why do I have to pass by ref?

```
function bind($resource, $binds)
{
    foreach ($binds as $key => $val) {
        $variable = &$binds[$key][0];
        $length = (isset($binds[$key][1])) ? $binds[$key][1] : -1;
        $type = (isset($binds[$key][2])) ? $binds[$key][2] : SQLT_CHR;
        oci_bind_by_name($resource, $key, $variable, $length, $type);
                        }
}
```

Comment: Re: Update; you shouldn't need to do that. The function in my answer works as written for me (PHP 7.0.17, InstantClient 12.1, Oracle 11gR2)

Comment: i am using php7.0.17 and your function works, however if I put them in variable I have to use `pass by ref` for it to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented (albeit obscurely) on the `oci_bind_by_name` manual page in a comment for [Example #3 Binding with a foreach() loop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#example-2191):

```
foreach ($ba as $key => $val) {
    // oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $val) does not work
    // because it binds each placeholder to the same location: $val
    // instead use the actual location of the data: $ba[$key]
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $ba[$key]);
}
```

So you should change your function like so (vars renamed to avoid line wrapping):

```
function bind($resource, $binds)
{
    foreach ($binds as $key => $val) {
        oci_bind_by_name($resource, $key, $binds[$key][0], $binds[$key][1], $binds[$key][2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: life save thank you. however I still dont understand why it does not work as it worked teh way I have done it, as it works when passing by ref

Comment: `oci_bind_by_name` simply points to a variable, and the data in that variable is changing with each `foreach` iteration. So if the last iteration set `$val = 'x'` your statement would look like: `insert into x (a, b, c, ...) values ('x', 'x', 'x', ...);`.

Comment: but each loop is setting `oci_bind_by_name` same as putting them individually line by line. is this just the way it works?

Comment: This answer works, but why is it working like this, Oracle?!

Comment: Why Oracle, why????? (it took me 4 hours to figure this out and it still makes no sense, specially as it has worked differently with OCI8 2.0.x

Comment: In case anybody wonders: inside your loop, you reuse the variable that holds the value: So in `foreach ($a as $key->$val)` the variable `$val` will be reused on every iteration of the loop, so all your binds will be bound to only one variable, with one value. So you will basically be inserting the same value in all columns,  whatever value you have in `$val` after the foreach ends.